# SharePoint masterpage css styles not showing for other users

Tags: css, sharepoint, master-pages, stylesheet

I'm setting up a SharePoint Site where the masterpage is built using one of the existing masterpages as a starting point (Blue Band).

When I test the site while logged in as the super admin, everything looks fine. But if I log in as a general user the default masterpage shows as Blue Band again.

I'm guessing there must be some permissions problem where the new CSS isn't allowed to show. It appears to just be the CSS as the placement of elements is as per the new master page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This usually happens to me when the CSS file is not published or approved yet. Where is your new CSS located? Have a look with SharePoint Designer or browse to it and publish/approve it.

Comment: And if your masterpage contains a reference to the CSS file make sure that is published/approved as well.

Comment: Yes. Exactly the issue. Thanks. :)

Comment: Please help on the steps you needed to do to fix your issue. Is it that you did not check in your reference or did you have to check in the css file?

Answer (score 1):

Must be published as a major version.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Why?

Answer (score 0):

To improve this question, if you are using an external CSS File, make sure it is not checked out to your Admin user or whoever was working on it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).