# SharePoint: CSS changes update in FireFox but not IE

Tags: css, sharepoint, internet-explorer, firefox, caching

Weird problem. I update the site CSS sheet and the changes show straight away in FireFox but don't show in IE. Using the Developer Toolbar in both apps the style changes are missing in IE. I've reset the browser cache but no dice.

Comment: Do you use the same user to login into the both application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231060/sharepoint-masterpage-css-styles-not-showing-for-other-users) might help you.

Comment: Yes, publishing and approving does fix it. It just seems such a convoluted process to test CSS tweaks. Firefox works off the bat but IE requires the full publishing process. The problem being that IE CSS renders differently to compliant CSS. Thought there would be a simple way to get this to work. Guess not. :(

Comment: Strange that Firefox shows the changes without publishing. Normally changes are only shown immediately if you're logged in with the an administrator account or with the user who did the changes. Perhaps you're using different users to log in to Firefox an IE?!?

Comment: Doh! That's it. I was setting up in Firefox with the admin account and then testing in IE with a user account. Thanks for that.

Comment: No problem. A time ago I had the same problem.